# Best disassembler tool for the .NET reflector?

Tags: c#, .net, reflector, disassembly

What's the best disassembler tool for the .NET reflector?

By best I mean, saving a .NET assembly in a disassembled state in most readable, most likely to compile with fewer changes.

The current one I use doesn't show simplified enumeration but shows the full IEnumerable implementations with MoveNext, etc with member names like:

```
this.<>4__state
CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3
```

Btw I am not trying to steal code, just trying out certain things on an already existing assembly instead of writing a similar thing from scratch. In the end, it's what I will learn from this that will stay, not the modified assembly.

Comment: Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V + modification usually worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it also shows members in this way, as in non eligible or use of invalid chars like $, etc.

Comment: Only Lutz Roeder is smart enough to write the code to decompile that.  He's busy, Microsoft hired him.  Don't expect him to re-surface for another 7 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Gate has fixed several bugs with the decompiling and is currently available in the Reflector 7 beta download at: http://reflector.red-gate.com/Download.aspx (it is the big red button to the right of the page).

You may also want to ensure the disassembler is using .Net 4 optimization - this provides the closest to actual source code for things like automatic properties and other new syntax stuff.  You can check this by going to the View -> Options and make sure the item selected in the Optimization list is .NET 4.0.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks man, it works for sure, not 100% in all cases but very good.

Answer (score 2):

Check out GrayWolf at www.DigitalbodyGuard.com

It has the ability to view IL and C#, and a basic ability to edit IL

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK they will produce roughly the same code, as Reflector is actually translating the IL to C#, not the Reflector plugin.

I would just use the [Reflector.FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) and fix up the code.  If it's a lot of code, it could be a considerable effort.